# Exchange 2003 / Blackberry Event Error 9667

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, blackberry

I have the following Error repeated in my Windows 2003 server event viewer, which I am thinking is related to my blackberry server because it is the user 'besadmin'.  Anyone know what might be causing this error?  Also, if I can't figure it out, how would I increase the quota as a workaround?

EDIT: Also, I haven't actually noticed any problems from a users standpoint. Can anyone explain what this error might actually mean?

> Event Type:   Error Event
>   Source:   MSExchangeIS Event
>   Category: General  Event ID:  9667
>   Date:     5/28/2009 Time:     10:44:31 AM
>   User:     N/A Computer:   MAILSERVER
>   Description: Failed to create a new
>   named property for database
>   "MYDOMAIN\MAILSTORENAME" because the
>   number of named properties reached the
>   quota limit (8192).  User attempting
>   to create the named property:
>   "besadmin"  Named property GUID:
>   0002...............  Named property name/id: "X-Vitals"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of named properties for your mailbox store (see Jason Nelson's very funny [article on named properties](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/04/06/451003.aspx) at the EHLO blog). This problem was just fixed in Exchange 2007 SP1 rollup 8, but that doesn't help you because you're on Exchange 2003. You can adjust the limit used for the named property list by following the directions in MS KB article 820379 (it seems to have been pulled but you can find a copy [here](http://www.netomatix.com/Articles/KBArticle.aspx?a=820379)).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Logs on the blackberry server to see if there is anything reported at the blackberry end?

Comment: There are quite a few logs even for one day, any recommendations for what to look for?

Answer (score -1):

The problem you have here is not BES related, but Exchange.

Error 9667 indicates you have run out of Named Properties for Exchange to user. This [Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb851492.aspx) does a better job than I could of explaining what they are.

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb851495.aspx) provides details of how to recover from this problem. You can increase the number of Named Properties availble using the instructions described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb851493.aspx). However if you have allready preciously done this, and you are at the maximum number of named properties, 32,766 then the only way to recover from this is to create a new mailbox database and move your mailboxes to that DB.

Whilst these articles talk about Exchange 2007, the registry key for increasing the number of named properties is the same for Exchange 2003, I have used these myself on an Exchange 2003 server.

Comment: the solution you link to is Exchange 2007 only; the OP is running Exchange 2003.

Comment: It seems there are not any articles on this problem for Exchange 2003, however the process for altering the registry key to increase the amount of named properties is the same for Exchange 2003